# php - regex - catch string inside multiple tags

Tags: php, regex, tags

still on regex! ;-)))

Assuming we have an html file with a lot of `<tr>` rows with same structure like this below, where `(.*?)` is the content i need to extract!

```
<tr align=center><th width=5%><a OnClick="(.*?)"href=#>(.*?)</a><td width=5%>(.*?)<td width=5% align=center >(.*?)</td></tr>
```

**UPDATED**

maybe with a nice **preg_match_all()** ?

i need something like this result

```
match[0] . match[1] . match[2] . match[3]
```

just in case someone need someting similar!

**THE SOLUTION** to my little problem is

`/<a\s*OnClick=\"(.*?)\"href=#>(.*?)<\/a><td[^>]+>(.*?)<td[^>]+>(.*?)<\/td><\/tr>/m`

thanks for the time!

Luca Filosofi!

Comment: Please tell me you are not asking how to parse html with a regex... the demons will come...

Comment: Oh, good. Nobody linked to that question in a week, I almost forgot it. (/waiting...)

Comment: Well i was being lazy... but since you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: question updated! ;-))))

Comment: @prodigitalson: the <tr structure is always the same i don't think there is any problem catching this with regex!?

Comment: I must admit I still don't understand. What isn't working with the regex you've posted? And is the whitespace distribution really that weird?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker: the # can be a normal attribute value, like align=center or width=5% can you understand now!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildly guessing here without actual sample data to match the regex against - also quite unhappy with having to use a regex here. Unless your tables always look exactly alike, I doubt you'll have much fun with regexes.

Anyway, all the caveats aside, this might work:

```
<tr[^>]+><th[^>]+><a OnClick="([^"]+)"\s*href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a><td[^>]+>([^<]+)<td[^>]+>([^<]+)</td></tr>
```

It expects the tags (and the attributes within the `<a>` tag) exactly in this order, no angle brackets within quoted strings, no escaped quotes within quoted strings etc. etc. (all those things that you wouldn't have to worry about if you used a parser).

In PHP:

```
preg_match_all('%<tr[^>]+><th[^>]+><a OnClick="([^"]+)"\s*href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)</a><td[^>]+>([^<]+)<td[^>]+>([^<]+)</td></tr>%', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

`$result` then is an array where `$result[0]` contains the entire match, `$result[1]` contains capturing group no. 1, etc.

Comment: not exactly, what i was looking for... but it helped me a lot! ps: i'm learnig regex here by asking question and step by step i'm learning! ;-) thanks again! `<a\s*OnClick=\"(.*?)\"href=#>(.*?)<\/a><td[^>]+>(.*?)<td[^>]+>(.*?)<\/td><\/tr>`